# Group accounts by 1 condition vs 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a count of `pat_id` that were either only "Sent" or only "Sent and Received"

Here is my query so far

```
select pat_id,
(case when addr_msg_actn_c in(1) then 'Sent' else convert(varchar(10),'Received') end) [Status]
from pat_addr_verif
where   pat_id in ('Z1000354','Z1000363','Z1000392','Z1000394')
group by pat_id, addr_msg_actn_c
order by pat_id
```

Which generates this output

[image: Current Output]

However, I'd like to simplify the output to display like this

[image: My Desired Output]

Comment: what is your question? what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry, how do I update my query to transform the first picture into the second? Notice how in the first picture account Z1000354 was ONLY "Sent" and account Z1000363 was both "Sent" and "Received." I'd like to group the rows such that account Z1000354 tells me it was only "Sent" and account Z1000363 indicates it was "Sent and Received." Is this possible?

Comment: Hey Gabe, what versaion of sql server do you have?

Comment: is there a specific value for "received"? or is it just that anything not a 1(sent) is received?

Comment: Hey @zip I'm using SQL Server 2014, version 12.0.2000.8.

Comment: @Jeremy yes so before I added the case statement, "Sent" was originally a 1 and "Received" was originally a 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small proof of concept. You can generate a case statement on the sum of a value to choose which text string you want.

```
   CREATE TABLE #SentReceive (
    Pat_ID NVARCHAR(8)
    ,[status] TINYINT
    )

INSERT INTO #SentReceive
VALUES (    'Z1000354'  ,1  )
    ,(    'Z1000354'  ,1  )
    ,(  'Z1000363'  ,1  )
    ,(  'Z1000363'  ,2  )
    ,(  'Z1000392'  ,2  )
    ,(  'Z1000394'  ,1  )
    ,(  'Z1000394'  ,2  )

SELECT pat_id
    ,sentstatus = CASE sum(distinct [status])
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'Sent'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'Received'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'Sent and Received'
        END
FROM #SentReceive
GROUP BY pat_id
ORDER BY pat_id
```

Comment: Jeremy, this is super helpful. The only issue though (and this is my fault for not mentioning it) is that there are cases within this dataset where a single account may have as much as 6 sent's, and no received's.

Comment: @GabeVerzino modified to take that into account

Comment: Oh AWESOME. Simple, and most easy to interpret. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
create table SentReceive
(
Pat_ID nvarchar(8),
SentOnly nvarchar(8)
)

insert SentReceive
values
('Z1000354','Sent'),
('Z1000363','Sent'),
('Z1000363','Received'),
('Z1000392','Sent'),
('Z1000394','Sent'),
('Z1000394','Received')

select distinct a.Pat_ID,
    case
        when b.SentOnly is not null then
            case a.SentOnly
                when 'Received' then b.SentOnly + ' and ' + a.SentOnly
                else a.SentOnly + ' and ' + b.SentOnly
            end
        else a.SentOnly
    end as Status
from SentReceive a
    left join SentReceive b on a.Pat_ID = b.Pat_ID and a.SentOnly <> b.SentOnly
```

I did a quickie with only the available data that you provided. If there are other variations in your dataset then you will need to account for that and it may or may not change what I came up with. Good luck!

Comment: Doua this framework got me there, with some minor tweaking! 

Final query:

select distinct a.pat_id,
    case when b.ADDR_MSG_ACTN_C is not null then 'Sent and Received' else 'Sent Only' end as Status
from pat_addr_verif a
    left join pat_addr_verif b on a.pat_id = b.pat_id and a.ADDR_MSG_ACTN_C <> b.ADDR_MSG_ACTN_C
where a.pat_id in ('Z1000354','Z1000363','Z1000392','Z1000394')

Comment: i'm glad it was helpful; looking at your final query below, there were other pieces of information missing from your original question. nonetheless, it's about learning and adapting to what's in front of you, which is what you did well (in this case).

Comment: appreciate your time, and your response was great. plus you're new on here! in no time, i'm sure you'll have plenty reputation points :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
;with cte as
(
select 1 as _order, 'Z1000354' as pat_id, 'Sent' as SentOnly
union select 2, 'Z1000363', 'Sent'
union select 3, 'Z1000363', 'Received'
union select 4, 'Z1000392', 'Sent'
union select 5, 'Z1000393', 'Received'
union select 5, 'Z1000394', 'Sent'
union select 6, 'Z1000394', 'Received'
) 
select pat_id, replace(_Status,',',' and') as _Status
from(
select distinct pat_id, 
STUFF((Select ', '+SentOnly  
from cte T2
where T1.pat_id=T2.pat_id
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as _Status from cte T1
) a
where _Status in (' Sent', ' Sent, Received')
```

Comment: Thanks @zip ! Yet another way to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Final query with some help from above posters:

```
    select distinct a.pat_id,
    case when b.ADDR_MSG_ACTN_C is not null 
         then 'Sent and Received' else 'Sent Only' end as Status
from pat_addr_verif a
left join pat_addr_verif b on a.pat_id = b.pat_id and 
          a.ADDR_MSG_ACTN_C <> b.ADDR_MSG_ACTN_C
where   a.pat_id in ('Z1000354','Z1000363','Z1000392','Z1000394')
```

[Correct Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lWEX.png)